# Excel formula to get last not empty value of an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I get the formula to fill yellow row?
Values in each row are not sorted, can have any numbers of values, and I need in yellow row get the last row not empty.
Any idea?
Thanks!

[image: Excel capture]

Comment: Try: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A5<>""),A2:A5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above. In a simpler way using `LOOKUP()` function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A6`

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A5<>""),A2:A5),"")
```

---

And Fill Across.

Comment: I tested this kind of solution for large data set and it has worse performance than `TOCOL/TAKE` combination, but I haven't tried this variant using the new `XLOOKUP`, maybe it has better performance: `=BYCOL(A2:D5, LAMBDA(x, XLOOKUP(2,1/(x<>""),x,"",-1,-1)))`

Comment: @DavidLeal It won't make a difference. The issue in performance is the fact that an array is being processed. The version of your formula with `FILTER` will perform no better than Mayukh's here. Basically, if null strings are present then it negates a whole host of binary/efficient approaches.

Comment: May be it will work better, but its an alternative approach. And this approach has been used a million times. `LOOKUP()` function is very old, its there since VisiCalc and then there was no such functions like `TOCOL()` or `TAKE()` so at that time also people were using it without any issues i hope so. I have known people who ae using Excel for 20/25 years they still use it even if they ae `MS365` users.

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley I meant comparing `LOOKUP` with `TOCOL/TAKE` I haven't tested the `FILTER` approach. Maybe because `TOCOL` doesn't really carry out an array evaluation.

Comment: @DavidLeal Ah, certainly `TOCOL/TAKE` has a big performance advantage over `LOOKUP`. Again, though, it all depends whether null strings are present or not. If only MS had added an additional option to `TOCOL`'s second parameter to ignore them!

Comment: I know @MayukhBhattacharya I tend to try using the new functions whenever is possible, since it is Microsoft recommendation. It is a valid approach, and even works for empty values as result of a formula: `=""` I just tried to adapt it using the new `XLOOKUP` and shared it here.

Comment: So you mean to say Microsoft has asked not to use `LOOKUP()` function anymore can you show me an instance where it has been clearly stated do not use these specific functions. any where. `LOOKUP()` function is still used by many and many do not have access to MS365. There are people still using Excel 2010.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya in general you can find such disclaimer or recommendation from Microsoft for old equivalent function such as `HLOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`. For [LOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) in specific in the **Tip** section, it is mentioned equivalent `XLOOKUP` is not just faster, but more versatile. Obviously if you have O365, if not, then you are forced to use the old equivalent functions.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tag listed in the question*, you can try the following (*formula 1*):

```
=BYCOL(A2:D5, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(TAKE(TOCOL(x,1),-1),"")))
```

or using `XLOOKUP` as follows (*formula 2*):

```
=BYCOL(A2:D5, LAMBDA(x, XLOOKUP("*",x,x,"",2,-1)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

There are multiple ways to find the last non-empty value, I have seen that: `TAKE(TOCOL(x,1),-1)` has the best performance among other approaches and it also works for text and numbers. `TOCOL` with the second input argument as `1`, remove empty rows and `TAKE` extract the last element.

**Note**: The above formulas assume empty cells has no value, but if the empty value is entered as follows `=""`(as a result of a formula) or a literal array: `{1;2;3;""}` it doesn't produce the expected result. To include this case, you can try the following:

```
=BYCOL(A2:D5, LAMBDA(x, TAKE(FILTER(x,x<>"",""),-1)))
```

or

```
=BYCOL(A2:D5, LAMBDA(x, TAKE(FILTER(x,LEN(x),""),-1)))
```

The performance is slightly worse than *formula 1* approach. For example for `100K` random rows with empty string values *formula 1* takes `0ms` most of the time, whereas the `FILTER` solution takes `10ms` on average.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you've assumed that all empty cells are 'genuinely' empty and so do not, for example, contain null strings ("").

Comment: Thanks, True @JosWoolley I added the approach to consider this case.

Comment: I like the `LEN` version serving as a reminder that in Excel `0` means `FALSE`, while any other integer means `TRUE`.

Comment: I like your Formula 2. I would suggest an improvement: `=BYCOL(TRIM(A2:D5), LAMBDA(x, XLOOKUP("?*",x,x,"",2,-1)))` In this way you eliminate cells with only spaces in them and the ones where the only character is '

Comment: Thanks. I had this approach too, but I removed because it fails in some non happy path. May be adding `TRIM` it gets resolved. I need to check.

Comment: Also, I think that XLOOKUP("`?*` is another improvement because it forces the text to have at least one character length.

Comment: @Florin It failed for the case: `={1;2;3;""}` that is why I removed it, but adding `TRIM` it works. The problem is that `TRIM` is a text function, so it converts the result to text. The solution should not transform the input. The only way to avoid weird cases so far are`TAKE/FILTER` formula, @MayukhBhattacharya solution or `XLOOKUP` version I added in the comment of his answer.

Comment: @DavidLeal, you are correct with the numbers vs text. I assumed all his values are text because the value `1.4` is aligned to the left like the others. If the data is ensured to be clean (no mix of numeric and text), then the `XLOOKUP` is up to 10 times faster than `TAKE/FILTER`. But the time for `XLOOKUP` depends on the row where the last non-empty cell is in the table and in the extreme case, with only the top rows being non-empty, it will be only 2 times as fast (I tested for 4 columns and 1,000,000 rows).      It has been fun. Thank you for your solution.